# Emberjs scroll to top when changing view

Tags: ember.js

When the main view of my application is switched (new route that reconnects the main outlet of my application controller) I want the page to be scrolled to the top. Otherwise it's a bit strange that I navigate to another page-like view and the viewport is still lost somewhere where I left off.

I hacked a solution and wonder if there's a better way or if anyone has the same thing.

Here's what I do:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  connectOutlet: function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably try and extend `Ember.Route` and add your `window.scrollTo` in the `enter` callback. Then instead of using Ember's `Route` for your leaf routes, you call your route .`extend()`, so they'll automatically scroll up when you *enter* a route/state. Something *similar* to this:

```
// define your custom route and extend "enter"
var MyRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    enter: function(router) {
        // for now on, all the routes that extend this, 
        // will fire the code in this block every time
        // the application enters this state
        // do whatever you need to do here: scroll and whatnot
    }
});

App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'hash',
    index: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                ...
            },
            // on your leaf routes, use your own custom route that 
            // does your scroll thing or whatever you need to do 
            home: MyRoute.extend({
                route: '/',
                connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                     ...
                }
            }),
            // other routes...
       })
});
```

does it make sense?

Comment: Your approach perfectly answers the question. Yes, it seems to be about the leave routes and not about the application controller.

Comment: You could also reopen Ember.Route and check on every "enter" event if this.childStates.length is 0 so you know it's a leave route. Both approaches leave the responsibility to you to call this._super if you need to use the "enter" event in specific routes.

Comment: Just keep in mind that reopening `Ember.Route` is that you'd be overtiring the `enter` feature for **all** routes. You might wanna keep the original functionality in the framework and extend on your own lib.

Comment: For newer ember users stumbling onto this, `Route#enter` is a private hook, you should use `Route#activate`.  In either case, make sure you call `this._super.apply(this, arguments);` from within your method.

Answer (score 20):

@Baruch's solution is good, but when I implemented it I had render on elements within my application state and would cause a scrollTop when it was not needed.

I found this to be much more effective as it only runs on the path change:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  currentPathChanged: function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }.observes('currentPath')

});
```

Answer (score 9):

I achieved this with the following code:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  render: function(controller, model) {
    this._super();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Coffee Script:

```
Ember.Route.reopen
    activate: ->
      @_super()
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

Javascript:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  activate: function() {
      this._super();
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth this is the approach that is prescribed officially by the Ember docs, at least in the cookbook: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/resetting_scroll_on_route_changes/

And this is also the only approach that worked for my situation, using the latest ember-cli, I had to create a mixin and pull it in on every affected route. Couldn't get it to fire on the application route for all children routes.

Answer (score 1):

It's now `render(name, options)`, and if you are specifically calling render (ie with a modal) you want to pass that to super()

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  render: function(name, options) {
    if (name != null) {
      return this._super(name, options);
    } else {
      return this._super();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ember 3.12+**  (this is technically 3.20 code listed here)

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  init() {
    // call event everytime route changes
    this.on('routeDidChange', () => {
      this._super(...arguments);
      window.scrollTo(0, 0); // scrolls to top
    });
  }
});

Router.map(function () {
  // your mapping code goes here
});

export default Router;
```

**Prior to 3.12** (this is technically 3.4 but the key code should be the same)

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  didTransition() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   }
});

Router.map(function () {
  // your mapping code goes here
});


export default Router;
```

We have handled this problem serveral times and the way we've found that is the easiest and most straight-forward way is to configure this once in the router.js file using a 'route transition' event function. We used `didTransition` before it got deprecated in Ember 3.12 in lieu of `routeDidChange`. I've posted both examples below. Some syntax may differ slightly depending on which version of Ember you are on but this core code should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for keeping this thread up to date!

Comment: No problem :) Glad my post is still relevant haha